LyX dark mode __
I switch between day and dark mode in my OS (Fedora 40) quite frequently and most apps follow this and change their color scheme. LyX doesn't. Until now I thought that this was not implemented in LyX, however I just saw this:

which makes me wonder whether this is actually implemented and somehow not working just for me.
PS: I am not talking about changing the color scheme manually, which is very tedious and usually you do it once when you install and you keep it. I am talking about the app changing automatically the colors according to the setting of the operating system, including the text area but also the windows themselves.
LyX version:
Version 2.4.1
(Monday, July 1, 2024)

Qt Version (run-time): 6.7.2 on platform wayland
Qt Version (compile-time): 6.7.1
OS Version (run-time): Fedora Linux 40 (Workstation Edition)
Python detected: 3.12.5 (/usr/bin/python3)


What is your LyX version?

@scottkosty added info to the question.

Thanks for adding the info. Thanks to LyX 2.4's support for dark mode (https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX.NewInLyX24#darkmode), we should be able to figure this out. See here for instructions on using qt5ct (or qt6ct depending): https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg219928.html. Note that the title of the thread mentions Windows but actually the instructions are for Linux. It works for me on Ubuntu.

Thanks for the links, @scottkosty. I installed qt5ct and defined QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct, but still does not seem to work.

It appears you're using Qt 6. So use qt6ct instead.

Note that you need a Qt style that supports dark mode. Qt styles are set in Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > User Interface > User interface style. Amongst others, Adwaita, Breeze, and Fusion should support dark mode.
